# Issues with Hadoop upgrade from hadoop 1.1.2 to hadoop 2.9.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, namenode

I am trying to upgrade Hadoop from 1.1.2 to 2.9.0

I had executed the command `start-dfs.sh -upgrade` on hadoop 2.9.0 cluster.

It shows that upgrade is in process and not yet finalized. I have been waiting for long but still showing the same status.

How to track the status of upgrade process?

Comment: Look at /var/log? Or a logs folder in `HADOOP_HOME`? Personally, I would have stood up a separate cluster entirely with new versions, then copied over datanodes using distcp and whatever else like Hive and Hbase tables

Comment: Finalizing upgrade is separate process that should be invoked manually after you confirm that data migration went well. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Upgrade_and_Rollback

Comment: @cricket_007 I have checked in /var/logs as well as logs file but couldnt find appropriate information. Is there any command to check the status of upgrade?

Comment: Not that I know of. I've always used Ambari or Cloudera Manager to do an upgrade

Comment: @cricket_007 How should I safegaurd the metadata. Should I take a backup of metadata before the upgrade process

Comment: Namenode metadata? Snapshot the fsimage?

Comment: Namenode metadata